# Using same method on different classes

Tags: c#, database, lambda

I'm created a method that separate the data for an SQLite database into 3 categories:

- Modified (variables in list_1 that are not equals to the list_2 ones)
- Created (variables in list_1 that are not found in list_2)
- Deleted (list_2 variables that are not existing anymore in list_1)

  *sidenote: list_2 is a backup of list_1 before any modification*

The problem with this code is that I can use it only on one class. If I want a second class, then I have to write down the same code again with minor changes. I have now 3 classes, but in the future, I probably want more. It'll be pretty time consuming if I try to write down over and over with every single class, so I posted this question for any suggestion. Also because I didn't find any articles where it uses lambda expressions.

```
public class Stats
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class FactStats : Stats
{
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public float balance { get; set; }

    public FactStats ShallowCopy()
    {
        return (FactStats)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

List<FactStats> Factions = new List<FactStats>();
List<FactStats> SavedFactions = new List<FactStats>();

void SavetoDatabase()
{
    //1. Separate Data
    List<FactStats> F_JoinedList = new List<FactStats>();
    List<int> F_Modify = new List<int>();
    List<int> F_Create = new List<int>();
    List<int> F_Delete = new List<int>();

    //Modified Objects
    F_JoinedList = Factions.Where(n => SavedFactions.Any(o => o.id == n.id)).ToList();
    foreach (FactStats f in F_JoinedList)
    {
        FactStats fs = SavedFactions.Single(x => x.id == f.id);
        if (!f.CompareEquals(fs))
            F_Modify.Add(f.id);
    }

    //Created Objects
    foreach (FactStats f in Factions)
    {
        bool vane = Convert.ToBoolean(SavedFactions.Where(f2 => f2.id == f.id).Count());
        if (!vane)
            F_Create.Add(f.id);
    }

    //Deleted Objects
    foreach (FactStats f in SavedFactions)
    {
        bool vane = Convert.ToBoolean(Factions.Where(f2 => f2.id == f.id).Count());
        if (!vane)
            F_Delete.Add(f.id);
    }

    ...
}
```

I've tried to do it with reflection, not much success. Probably because of my lack of experience.

[CompareEquals](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1046263/Comparing-Two-Complex-Objects-of-the-Same-Class) extensive method (at the Modified Objects) is a third party code that compare two objects of the same class using reflection.

Comment: A DataTable has similar functionality. If you need to roll your own maybe you could check the source code on the DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use one method on different classes is to use Generic method. Since classes are different they should conform to the common interface, for example IUniqueIdentifiable should have "id" property.
You need to create method:

```
void Save<T>(List<T> saved, List<T> modified) where T: IUniqueIdentifiable
{
    List<T> F_JoinedList = new List<T>();
    List<int> F_Modify = new List<int>();
    List<int> F_Create = new List<int>();
    List<int> F_Delete = new List<int>();

    //Modified Objects
    F_JoinedList = modified.Where(n => saved.Any(o => o.id == n.id)).ToList();
    foreach (T f in F_JoinedList)
    {
        T fs = saved.Single(x => x.id == f.id);
        if (!f.CompareEquals(fs))
            F_Modify.Add(f.id);
    }

    //Created Objects
    foreach (T f in modified)
    {
        bool vane = Convert.ToBoolean(saved.Where(f2 => f2.id == f.id).Count());
        if (!vane)
            F_Create.Add(f.id);
    }

    //Deleted Objects
    foreach (T f in saved)
    {
        bool vane = Convert.ToBoolean(modified.Where(f2 => f2.id == f.id).Count());
        if (!vane)
            F_Delete.Add(f.id);
    }

   ...

}

    public interface IUniqueIdentifiable
    {
       id {get;}
    }
```

There are tons of articles how to create Generic method, you can find one sample below
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=605369&seqNum=4